# phpmyadmin replacing table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can I replace a table in DB through phpmyadmin. Table has two foreign keys and I can truncate it by disabling foreign key checks (or delete it completely), however when I try to reupload it, if I don't enable foreign key checks it doesn't connect to the tables it should (I can't click on foreign ID, usually it takes me to the related table). If I do enable foreign key checks I get an error

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Is there a way to somehow replace a table with the same table from the past by keeping the relations alive?

Answer (score 0):

i think the table contains data ... try clearing the table before dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually **"you don't need to disable foreign key checks"** if you want to delete from (or truncate) only the table(s) where child records are stored. You should be able to delete all and re-insert them later. Please try it this way.
>
> You need to disable the foreign key checks if you want to truncate the tables with primary keys without deleting the child records. (This is not reasonable though.)
>
> The following steps in order should work fine without disabling any constraint. If you don't follow the order, it will fail. You can skip the steps 2 and 3 and use 1 and 4 only.
>
> 1. Delete all child records with foreign key pointing to a primary key.
> 2. Delete all master records with primary key.
> 3. Re-insert all master records with primary key.
> 4. Re-insert all child records with foreign key pointing to a primary key.

Anyway, the error you get sounds like when you try to insert the old data, the matching record is missing in the master table where the foreign key points to.

You can check:

1. Whether the data in the master tables (the tables with primary key where foreign keys point to) are also deleted or truncated. If so, you need to bring them back before the child records.
2. Whether the data in the master tables are not the same anymore and the consistency is lost with the old data. (If you are working on a production database, the data might be changing). If so, you need you need to bring the missing records back to the master table.